# How accurate is net view in big networks

Tags: networking, cmd.exe

How accurate is `net view` in big networks? Will it display all the computers in a big network? Does it only work on `WLAN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net view` is not reliable at all, it doesn't get info about other network segments. You are way better off querying Active Directory, for example dsquery might give what you want. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730720.aspx